# Targeting blockquote itemprop="reviewBody"

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to justify the text in my `reviewBody` attribute in CSS:

```
<blockquote class="wpcr3_content" itemprop="reviewBody">
```

How I can justify this one in CSS?

Comment: It works Tyler ! Thanks a lot ! Arnaud

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the selector: `blockquote[itemprop="reviewBody"] { color: red; }`

Example:

```css
blockquote[itemprop="reviewBody"] { color: red; }
```

```html
<blockquote class="wpcr3_content" itemprop="reviewBody">Testing...</blockquote>
<blockquote class="wpcr3_content" itemprop="review">Testing...</blockquote>
```